# Polymer 3.x, ajax requests (to port 8081) and PHP together in development

Tags: javascript, php, polymer, polymer-3.x

(sorry my english!)

Hi.

I have this question about how to use Polymer Cli during the development, together with Xampp / Apache / PHP for the ajax request.

Using "polymer serve" while I'm developing, how do I "send" the requests from ajax to the Xampp / Apache / PHP, I want to use during development, but also afterwards when I go into production.

If I do a build and put everything in htdoc, I correctly receive the responses of the request. But while I develop, using the polymer serve (using 8081 port), how do I send the requests to PHP?

Answer (score 0):

...oh god, all is working

example:

polymer serve --proxy-path services --proxy-target http://localhost/Polymer/3.x/myapp/services